# Python Regex Webcrawling, Get Double results, need just one

Tags: python, regex, web-crawler, findall

I am working on a basic python webcrawling program to go into a website and read the email addresses and show that as output. I am getting the right answer but it is getting duplicated. Can you please help to fix it?

Here is the program:

```
from re import findall
import urllib.request

url = "https://www.uta.edu/academics/schools-colleges/business/admissions-and-advising/cob-advising"

print("Email addresses for advisors:")

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

html = response.read()

htmlStr = html.decode()

pdata = findall(r"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+"
                     r"@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+"
                     r"\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}", htmlStr)

for item in pdata:
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two copies of all emails in the html file (one in text and another one in `href` attribute). Here is an example of this case:

```
<a href="mailto:micah.washington@uta.edu" class="uta-btn uta-btn-ghost">
<span>micah.washington@uta.edu</span>
</a>
```

The standard way would be to use a parser to only get the text of html and not the attributes/tags. But here, easiest way would be to print every other element:

```
for item in pdata[::2]:
    print(item)
```

And here is a more standard way of doing it using BeautifulSoup html parser where `div.text` extracts text of html and removes tags and attributes:

```
from re import findall
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "https://www.uta.edu/academics/schools-colleges/business/admissions-and-advising/cob-advising"

print("Email addresses for advisors:")

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

div = bs(response, 'html5lib')

pdata = findall(r"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+"
                     r"@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+"
                     r"\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}", div.text)

for item in pdata:
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in list(dict.fromkeys(pdata)):
    print(item)
```

"dict.fromkeys(pdata)" import list's items to its key. (In this case value will be None) When importing, same key value will be ignored.
Finally list(dict.fromkeys(pdata)) will make duplicated items to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You get each e-mail address twice, because your website contains each e-mail address two times. You can convert your list to a set to get only the unique items. You can then convert it back to a list, if you need the results in a list:

```
pdata = list(set(pdata))
```